# R: Issue Visualizing Data From Tibble

Tags: r, plot, tibble

I have this code that built the tibble below.

```
data.3<-data.1 %>% group_by(ICD10Code,PatientId) %>% 
summarise(ReferralSource=first(ReferralSource),NextAppt=first(NextAppt),Age=max(Age),
InsuranceName=toString(unique(InsuranceName))) %>% ungroup() %>% group_by(ICD10Code) %>% 
summarise(mAge = mean(Age, na.rm = T),Frequency=n())
```

Then I order the so I can see what are the most frequent values for the column "ICD10Code"

```
data.3[order(-data.3$Frequency),]
```

The result is this:

```
ICD10Code  mAge Frequency frequency
   <fct>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
 1 I10        51.0        86        86
 2 E119       47.8        35        35
 3 E782       51.1        27        27
 4 Z0000      51.1        21        21
 5 K219       42.6        18        18
 6 F418       41.8        17        17
 7 J449       57.2        17        17
 8 M545       51.8        17        17
 9 R030       49          16        16
10 J302       50.1        14        14
# … with 485 more rows
```

What I want to do is just plot the top 10 most frequent codes. At this point I would settle for anything to help me visualize this tibble. The tibble is exactly what I wanted to graph/plot off of, but it seems that everything I have has some error associated.

I have tried this:

```
top_n(data.3, n=10, data.3$Frequency) %>%
ggplot(., aes(x=data.3$ICD10Code, y=data.3$Frequency))+
geom_bar(stat='bin')
```

and result was:

```
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (23): x, y
```

also tried this:

```
top_n(data.3, n=10, data.3$Frequency) %>%
plot(x=data.3$ICD10Code,data.3$Frequency)
```

but get this:

```
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' and 'y' lengths differ
```

I have searched and tried different things from SO and can't seem to get anything to work. 
All I am trying to accomplish is to visualize the top 10 ICD10Code by Frequency and ICD10Code by mAge.

Comment: Try `top_n(data.3, n=10, Frequency) %>%
ggplot(., aes(x=ICD10Code, y=Frequency))+
geom_bar(stat='bin')`

Comment: For `ggplot`, make sure not to use `$` inside of aesthetics. You should just be using the column name and not the full data set name since you pass that in via the data= parameter. Also you can't easily pipe data into `plot()` with `%>%` since that's not a "tidyverse" function.  The pipe will dump your data into the first parameter and that's not where it goes with `plot()`. Try something more like `top_n(data.3, n=10, Frequency) %>% plot(Frequency~ICD10Code, data = .)`

Comment: @MrFlick. That was the trick. Thank you for your help!